# JUnit tests not running in order

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, amazon-dynamodb, junit5

I am using JUnit 5 to test DynamoDB, and I have a set up method annotated with @BeforeAll where I insert 3 items in the database, and one annotated with @AfterAll to delete the items in the database after all the test have run.

```
@Test
@Order(1)
public void addNewCar() {
    repository.save(new Car("d"));

    assertThat(repository.count()).isEqualTo(4);
}
```

I am inserting a new item first, and then I delete one item:

```
@Test
@Order(2)
public void deleteCar() {
    repository.deleteById("a");

    assertThat(repository.count()).isEqualTo(2);
}
```

However, the first test is failing (the count is 3 instead of 4) because the car that is deleted in test number 2 is already removed in test number 1.

I am able to solve it by running by annotating the setup and clean database methods with @BeforeEach and AfterEach, but I am curious why my item is already deleted in test 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test class also needs an annotation:

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
```